# Вопрос по Thymeleaf

Tags: java, веб-программирование, thymeleaf

Допустим есть простой Java объект(obj1) с полями, геттерами, сеттерами. Одно из полей ссылается на другой объект(obj2). Если я в таймлиф через метод addAtribute передам obj1, то можно ли из таймлифа получить доступ к полям класса obj2? И какой тогда будет синтаксис?

Comment: `${obj1.obj2.someField}` не работает?

Comment: да вот не сработало почему то

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, оказывается у ссылочных полей тип должен быть public. Удивлен, потому что у не ссылочных полей может быть тип private(проверял).
@SergeyGornostaev вы были правы.